# Phase distribution of coherent states

Tags: quantum-optics, coherent-states, quasiprobability-distributions

I am studying the phase distribution for coherent states, as is defined in quantum optics. (See, for example, Introductory Quantum Optics by [Gerry and Knight](https://ostad.hormozgan.ac.ir/ostad/UploadedFiles/1859694/1859694-9477415132068301.pdf), pages 46–48).

In this situation, we seek the phase probability distribution $P(\varphi)$ for a coherent state; then, we take

$$P(\varphi)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \left| \left\langle \varphi \right| \left. \alpha \right\rangle \right|^2 \tag{1}$$

where the factor $(1/2\pi)$ is to guarantee the normalization of the probability distribution, the state $\left|\alpha\right\rangle = e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left|\alpha \right|^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha^{n}}{\sqrt{n!}} \left|n \right\rangle$ is the coherent state, and $\left|\varphi \right\rangle = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{i\varphi n} \left| n\right\rangle$ is the state of phase as is defined by [Gerry and Knight](https://ostad.hormozgan.ac.ir/ostad/UploadedFiles/1859694/1859694-9477415132068301.pdf), Pag. 38; besides, $\left|n\right\rangle$ is the number state. Then, by utilizing these definitions in Eq. (1), we have

$$P(\varphi)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \left| \left(\sum_{n'=0}^{\infty} e^{-i\varphi n} \left\langle n'\right| \right)\cdot \left(e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left|\alpha \right|^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha^{n}}{\sqrt{n!}} \left|n \right\rangle\right) \right|^2 \\
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \left| \left(\sum_{n'=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-i\varphi n} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left|\alpha \right|^2} \frac{\alpha^{n}}{\sqrt{n!}} \delta_{n,n'}\right) \right|^2 $$
$$=\frac{1}{2\pi} \left| \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-i\varphi n} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left|\alpha \right|^2} \frac{\alpha^{n}}{\sqrt{n!}}\right) \right|^2,\tag{2}$$

Now, we use the polar form of $\alpha$, that is $\alpha=\left| \alpha\right|e^{i\theta}$; therefore, we can express the Eq. (2) as

$$P(\varphi)=\frac{e^{-\left|\alpha \right|^2}}{2\pi}\left| \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  e^{-in (\varphi-\theta)}  \frac{\left| \alpha\right|^{n}}{\sqrt{n!}}\right|^2. \tag{3}$$

Now comes the important step. Gerry and Knight invoke the fact that **the Poisson distribution can be approximated by a Gaussian for large** $\left|\alpha\right|^2$; then, they use the following approximation

$$e^{-\left|\alpha \right|^2/2} \frac{\left| \alpha\right|^{2n}}{n!} e^{-\left|\alpha \right|^2/2} e^{-\left|\alpha \right|^2} \approx \left(2\pi \left|\alpha \right|^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \exp\left[-\frac{(n-\left|\alpha \right|^2)^2}{2\left|\alpha \right|^2}\right]\tag{4} $$

in the sum of the Eq. (3) to evaluate it; then, they obtain

$$P(\varphi) \approx \left(\frac{2 \left|\alpha \right|^{2}}{\pi} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \exp \left[-2\left| \alpha \right|^2 (\varphi - \theta)^2 \right], \tag{5}$$

which represents a Gaussian centered at $\varphi=\theta$. **Then, my question is, how to use Eq. (4) in Eq. (3) to obtain the Eq. (5)?**